# Abstracting Core Data from the rest of the app (MVCS pattern)?

Tags: api, caching, core-data

I'm working on an app that is basically a client for a server-side REST API.

The app relies heavily on server-data (kind of like Facebook does).

In my app I have an ServerAPI class that manages all interaction with the server.  It basically acts as the "Store" in the "Model-View-Controller-Store" pattern.  The rest of the app uses a singleton instance of this class to access data.

So for example if one of my view controllers needs a list of Articles, it would call:

```
[[ServerAPI sharedAPI] fetchArticlesWithCompletion:^(NSArray *articles){
    // Do something with the new articles.
}];
```

This way the app doesn't care how the articles are fetched.  For all it knows, they were fetched from a local file and not a server.

This is all fine and well.

The problem now is I'd like to add some sort of caching.  After looking around it sounds like Core Data might be the best tool for the job (but I'm definitely open to other suggestions).

I found AFIncrementalStore (NSIncrementalStore subclass for AFNetworking) which looks promising.  But from my (currently limited) understanding of NSIncrementalStore, the app (view controllers) still interact directly with NSFetchRequests and MOCs to fetch data.

I'd like to keep my current API (ServerAPI singleton) and simply plug in Core Data "behind the scenes" so that the rest of the app remains unaware of the details.  Basically the app shouldn't know that data is cached, or how it is cached, it should just request data and get data.

So my question is, what's a good strategy for implementing this?  Has anyone done something like this before?  Is it worth the effort?  I understand that Core Data is itself a way of abstracting stores, so having a second layer of abstraction might be overkill.  But I keep thinking of the case where if one day I decide to use NSCoding instead of Core Data to store objects to disk.  I generally don't like having all my classes know about implementation details (in this case using core data vs not using core data).

I'm a little torn on what approach is best.  I don't want to invest too much time into a solution that might not make sense in the long run.

Generally does it make sense to use Core Data APIs directly in code?  Or is it best to abstract away all these details behind a custom DataManager that handles both server and local data.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use `RestKit` as the bridge between the RESTful API and Core Data. I would use Core Data and I wouldn't be thinking that changing to `NSCoding` might be a good idea in the future (that's a really very unlikely scenario). Core Data offers you a lot of options for storage, searching and memory management. Getting the same features from another store is going to be a lot of effort or a similar level of dependency.

Either way, you have 2 options - hide the cache or don't.

If you hide it, the side effect would be that you'd really need to call the completion block twice (first for the cache hit, second for the server response). How easy that will be depends on what you're doing. The issue would be that you wouldn't be able to leverage all of the search and memory management features of your cache (like only loading pages of data from the store and loading more as the user scrolls through a list).

If you don't hide it, yes you would use fetch requests and MOCs. Probably via `NSFetchedResultsController`. The impact is relatively low IMHO and the benefits are large (like the automatic page management). Now your structure is - view controllers watch the 'cache' for data (the `ServerAPI` owns the MOC so it still mediates the store), they can get existing data immediately and if they decide new data is required they call the `ServerAPI`. The `ServerAPI` works exactly as it does now (with the completion block) and the completion block is either used as a trigger to update the UI activity indication or as the actual source of data if needs be.

As you can probably tell, I wouldn't hesitate in using Core Data and allowing its features to be used in my view controllers. The part I'm interested in shielding the rest of the code from is the server API, not the local data cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've been trying to stay away from RestKit as it seems a little outdated and not very well supported.  Also I'm already using AFNetworking so I'd like to stick with that for the network connections.  After reading up more on this I think I'm going to go with the AFIncrementalStore route and see where that takes me.  Let's hope the Core Data gods are watching on me.

Comment: Fair enough. Just to note that RestKit isn't outdated in any way, it uses a number of latest technologies and is built on top of AFNetworking. It's also actively developed and has an active forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/restkit).